# Error installing griddb-python module using pip command

Tags: griddb

I encountered an issue while attempting to install the GridDB Python client for the purpose of testing various operations within the GridDB database. During the installation process, I encountered an error that hindered the successful installation of the 'griddb-python' package. The error, which appears to be related to the usage of SWIG (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator), is associated with the package's building process.

I have tried installing griddb-python  module using [Documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/python/#installation)

Followed Steps:

First step:

```
$ wget \
https://github.com/griddb/c_client/releases/download/v4.2.0/griddb_c_client-4.2.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm
```

Second Step:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh griddb_c_client-4.2.0-1.linux.x86_64.rpm
```

but getting the error:

```
sudo: rpm: command not found
```

then I have tried to install the module using the [Python PIP link](https://pypi.org/project/griddb-python/)
given in the documentation but encountered with an error:

```
pip install griddb-python
Collecting griddb-python
  Using cached griddb_python-0.7.6.tar.gz (52 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: griddb-python
  Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for griddb-python
Failed to build griddb-python
Installing collected packages: griddb-python
  Running setup.py install for griddb-python: started
  Running setup.py install for griddb-python: finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [8 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
  running build
  running build_ext
  building '_griddb_python' extension
  swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
  swig.exe -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb-python
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Running setup.py install for griddb-python did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [9 lines of output]
  running install
  C:\Users\hitman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_ext
  building '_griddb_python' extension
  swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
  swig.exe -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

griddb-python

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```